# GraphQL API is working locally but not when deployed to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

My project uses AWS and GraphQL (Amplify add api with DynamoDB). My `schema.graphql` is below:

```
type Post @model @auth(rules: [
    { allow: owner, operations: [delete, update, read]}
    # { allow: private, operations: [read, create], provider: userPools}
    { allow: public, provider: iam, operations: [read]}
    ])
  {
  id:ID!
  tag: String!
  title: String!
  content: String!
  photo: String
  owner: String
  category: String!
}

typescript
    const readBoards = async () => {
        const Boards = await API.graphql({query: listPosts, authMode: 'AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS'});
        const allBoards = Boards.data.listPosts.items;
        setBoardsItems(allBoards);
    };
```

On localhost I can see `listPosts` items but not at deploying site.
I allow public to read but why at deploying site I can't see the table?

localhost:

[image]

deployment site:

[image]

I checked several @auth mode changes.

I think that API Gateway, Proxy or CORS are the cause of my problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please inspect your network traffic in your browser dev tools to see what is happening with your graphql queries. That will help you spot CORS or other errors.

Comment: No queries in network tab.. How do I fix this problem?!

Comment: open network tab, reload page. Only need to observe XHR requests. You'll see a POST for every GraphQL query/mutation.

Comment: Observing XHR requests, there are no any query/mutation at network tab...

Comment: Could you see above picture?!

Comment: Yes - it looks like you have issues in your client code before you even make a network request.

Comment: Then I’m so curious why local is working and deployment version is not working by same code?